# dpkg: Upgrading depending packages (with the depended on possibly failing)

Tags: dpkg, dependencies, packaging

I have two packages A and B where B is an optional component that depends on package A and its exact version. Therefore I need to enure that if both packages are installed they are of the same version. To make it a little bit more complicated installation of package A can fail from the `preinst` script. In this case nothing should be upgraded

So if A and B are installed the desired behavior should be:

1. `dpkg --install A-new.deb`
   upgrade denied (since B is depending on A)
2. `dpkg --install B-new.deb`
   upgrade denied (since A needs to be upgraded first)
3. `dpkg --install A-new.deb B-new.deb`
   A and B upgraded
4. `dpkg --install A-new.deb B-new.deb` and upgrading A fails
   Nothing changed (i.e. old version of A and B in Installed state)

What I tried:

Adding A (with version) to B's `Depends:` line in the control file

1. `dpkg --install A-new.deb`
   A is upgraded, B remains the old version
2. `dpkg --install B-new.deb`
   B is upgraded but in Unpacked state, configuring denied due to the dependency
3. `dpkg --install A-new.deb B-new.deb`
   A and B are upgraded
4. `dpkg --install A-new.deb B-new.deb` and upgrading A fails
   A stays at the old version, B is new version in Unpacked state

So only 3. matches the desired behavior

Adding A (with version) to B's `Pre-Depends:` line in the control file

1. `dpkg --install A-new.deb`
   A is upgraded, B stays at the old version
2. `dpkg --install B-new.deb`
   upgrade denied due to the dependency
3. `dpkg --install A-new.deb B-new.deb`
   A is upgraded, B stays at the old version due to a pre-dependency problem
4. `dpkg --install A-new.deb B-new.deb` and upgrading A fails
   Nothing changed (i.e. old version of A and B in Installed state)

Here only 2. and 4. match the desired behavior

How can I get the desired behavior?

Comment: It's better to use `apt`.

Comment: While apt with the dependency defined in the `Pre-Depends:` line gives a behavior that's good enough (the desired one except for case 1. where it upgrades package A and removes B) I cannot force people to use apt. So how can I at least ensure that dpkg doesn't upgrade A and leaves the old version of B installed (current behavior for case 1.)?